# How to import module from parent directory without sys.path?

Tags: python, python-3.6

I am trying to call a module from a parent package.

My project structure -

```
be/
  __init__.py
  api/
    __init__.py
    models.py
  alembic/
    env.py
```

How to call `models.py` inside `env.py`

I tried like below,

```
from api.models import Base
```

I get the error - `ImportError: No module named 'api'`

I thought of restructuring by putting the `alembic` directory inside `api` directory, still not able to import `models`.

Using `sys.path` looks hacky, if I should change the project structure, then please suggest.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Importing modules from parent folder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/714063/importing-modules-from-parent-folder)

Comment: @vahdet - in this answer they are using `sys.path` which i want to avoid or `..` which is not supported in `python3.6`

Comment: You can use `PYTHONPATH` env variable

Comment: Try `from be.api.models import Base` or `from ..api.models import Base`

Comment: `..` support was dropped G_G, o didn't know that

Comment: I tried this - `from be.api.models import Base`, but it says `ImportError: No module named 'be'`

Comment: @Ejaz it is because you haven't export `PYTHONPATH` to `be`, you can check my answer

Answer (score 3):

You can use relative import

inside `env.py`, you only need `from ..api.models import Base`

If you don't want to use relative import, you can also try absolute import like

`from be.api.models import Base`

provided that you have exported the `PYTHONPATH` to `be` by

```
path_to_be=''
export PYTHONPATH=$path_to_be:$PATH
```

Answer (score 1):

Some suggetions:

1.) Just accept it and modify sys.path ;-)

2.) make sure the environment variable PYTHONPATH points to the parent directory (be) and call your script only then

Example:

```
export PYTHONPATH=/absolute/path/to/be
```

3.) add an `__init__.py` file into the directory alembic
and call your script from the `be` direcrory with.
python -m alembic.env

4.) add the `__init__.py` like for 3.) and a small wrapper script to the `be` directory and call that script from `be` this script will then import alembic.env and call it's 'main' function.

Don't hesitate to contact me if my suggestions aren't clear enough.

I don't know your context but I often prefer 3.) and 4.) as nobody has to know about environment variables or sys path changes.

Comment: or just move env.py to the `be` directory